# Google Autoload Maps Adsense Library

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm wondering how to autoload the Adsense library with Google Maps. Right now my script tag looks like this:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'maps','version':'3','other_params':'sensor=false'}]}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm unsure what the correct parameter is to autoload the Adsense library. In order to autoload packages with the Visualization API, the script tag looks like this:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization', 'version':'1.1', 'packages': ['geomap', 'corechart', 'imagebarchart']}]}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'd definitely appreciate any help with this—haven't been able to find anything yet, and I've tried messing with the parameters a couple different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guy on the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Group figured it out. The correct script tag should looking like this:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'maps','version':'3','other_params':'libraries=adsense%26sensor=false'}]}"></script>
```

Comment: still amazing to me that this is pretty much undocumented as far as I can find.

Comment: btw- you can use this to url encode the part after "autoload=" http://www.amazify.com/url-encoder-decoder